# Puppeteer - Is there a way to handle new windows in headless mode?

Tags: puppeteer, headless

I'm working in an application that requires these types of login where a new window (no tab) pops up and ask you to login, in the same way that twitter or facebook do (or used to do), where it shows where to put your email and password, click "login" and then the window would close and the main window would receive the authentication and keep going.

I can do it in "headed" mode, when I click the authentication button, the window pops up and I get a grip of it with

`const newWindow = (await browser.pages())[1]`

and then I'd navigate like normal where in my case I only have to click a single button because I'm already logged in the page I'm trying to use for authentication

`await newWindow.waitFor("//SomeXpath")`

`const buttonToClick= (await newWindow.$x("//SomeXpath"))[0]`

`await buttonToClick.click()`

Again, in headed mode it works fine. but in headless mode is like this 2nd page would not open.
If I try:

`console.log(await browser.pages())`

I only see the main page where I open puppeteer

I've seen people talking about the "target" class, but it seems is for new tabs, and the examples I've found didn't work for me (or probably I wasn't able to understand and properly use them)

I'm afraid that what I'm trying to do is not possible and I'm chasing a ghost.

Thanks

Edited:
A snapshot of the window with the button I have to click

[Snapshot of the new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV9ab.png)

Also I've tried this, but it didn't work either:

`const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated',  target => x(target.page())));`

`const popup = await newPagePromise;`

where popUp would be the new "page". But if I do a console.log(popup) it returns "null"

Comment: I'm facing the same problem as you.